# How to align my header and document in same?

Tags: alignment

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage[top=0.75in, bottom=0.75in, left=0.55in, right=0.85in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\fontfamily{SansSerif}
\selectfont

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage
%[ansinew]
[utf8]
{inputenc}
%----------------------------------------------------
%header and footer
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

%\rhead{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{../Downloads/sbstnpraveen@gmail.jpg} }
\lhead{Praveen Kallukalam Sebastian\\seen@gmail.com\\+9196333}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}
%----------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{mygrey}{gray}{.75}
\textheight=9.75in
\raggedbottom

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0in}
\newcommand{\isep}{-2 pt}
\newcommand{\lsep}{-0.5cm}
\newcommand{\psep}{-0.6cm}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\circ$}


%-----------------------------------------------------------
%Custom commands
\newcommand{\resitem}[1]{\item #1 \vspace{-2pt}}
\newcommand{\resheading}[1]{{\small \colorbox{mygrey}{\begin{minipage}{0.975\textwidth}{\textbf{#1 \vphantom{p\^{E}}}}\end{minipage}}}}
\newcommand{\ressubheading}[3]{
\begin{tabular*}{6.62in}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} r}
    \textsc{{\textbf{#1}}} & \textsc{\textit{[#2]}} \\
\end{tabular*}\vspace{-8pt}}

%-----------------------------------------------------------


\begin{document}

\hspace{0.5cm}\\[.3cm]

\indent\resheading{\textbf{OBJECTIVE} }\\[\lsep]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is that `\indent` doing there? and not `\noindent`?

Comment: i tried to align that sentence with my header it didnt worked. iam just new to latex... actually i need to put that OBJECTIVE align straight below to the header.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Probably you mean `\noindent`.

Comment: okke thanks when i used no indent it is align .....thnks

Comment: @praveen -- Does "it is align" mean your problem is solved?

Comment: when i used \noindent instead of \indent my problem got solved